# Java - Mostar tabla BBDD por consola

Tags: java, mysql

Busco imprimir por cosola los datos de una tabla de una BD(MySQL), pero a la hora de imprimir no muesta error ni los datos. Estoy siguiendo un curso de un libro. Dejo el código para que vean.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A cada vuelta de bucle debes añadir tu dto al ret. No te sale nada porque tienes tu colección vacía. También deberías revisar [cómo elaborar una buena pregunta.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Y ante todo buenas y bienvenido.

Comment: Por favor, pon el código relevante como texto, no como capturas de pantalla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta añadir tu objeto creado a tu lista de departamentos, por eso te aparece vacía, la recorres pero no lo almacenas.

```
while(rs.next()){
  dto = new DeptDTO();
  dto.setDeptno("blabla");
  dto.setDname("blabla");
  dto.setLoc("blabla");
  ret.add(dto);
}
return ret;
```

Espero que esto te ayude.

Saludos!